# SQL query with listagg (distinct ) and case statement

Tags: sql, oracle, string-aggregation, listagg

I need to use `listagg(distinct somestring)` except I need to select the records conditionally, hence I combine a case statement within the `listagg`.

here is a sample of the code which works :

```
listagg(case when  level_1='Brakes' and service_r_L>0.8 then  level_2 else null end  ,'+') within group (order by level_2 asc ) as Brake_services
```

however I need `listagg(DISTINCT level_2 , '+')` but I am unable to place the DISTINCT anywhere.

Sorry about the SQL code being in lower case, It is probably just me who does'nt bother to capitalise my SQL code.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Post your full query

Comment: Lower case SQL is just fine, no need at all to capitalize. (Back in the 80's upper case was the standard way, but that's a very long time ago.)

Answer (score 0):

Oracle 19c allows this: [LISTAGG DISTINCT in Oracle Database 19c](https://oracle-base.com/articles/19c/listagg-distinct-19c) In this article you can find two pre-19c solutions: prepare distinct values at first or use row_number(). There is also third way, regular expressions to remove duplicates in output. Here is first-way example, something which may help you. If it does not please edit your question, tell us which Oracle version you are using, show us your full query and sample data, preferrably use [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2) as I did it.

**<sup>[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=fcbb89e7e0a384e472d171f36f8f4e2d)</sup>**

```
select id_grp, listagg(case when level_1 = 'Brakes' and srl = 1
                            then level_2 end  ,'+') 
                       within group (order by level_2 asc ) as brake_services
  from (select distinct id_grp, level_1, level_2, 
               case when service_r_l > .8 then 1 else 0 end srl from t)
  group by id_grp
```